# Concurrent Access to Same Variable from different blocks - Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Accessing the variable `dictionary` from non-concurrent blocks are leading to crash, But I wanted to make the blocks non-concurrent,

The dummy operationN which will be replaced by some API calls in my project

How to achieve this feature

```
var dictionary: [Int: String] = [:]

private let queue = OperationQueue()

for entry in 1...20 {
    let operationN = BlockOperation {
        sleep(2)
        print("Operation ", entry)
        dictionary[entry] = ""
    }
    queue.addOperation(operationN)
}
```

PS: **I don't want to block the user. All these tasks should happen in background only.**

Answer (score 1):

Here is possible approach

```
var dictionary: [Int: String] = [:]
let guardQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "local.guard.Queue")

private let queue = OperationQueue()

for entry in 1...20 {
    let operationN = BlockOperation {
        sleep(2)
        print("Operation ", entry)
        guardQueue.sync {
           dictionary[entry] = ""
        }
    }
    queue.addOperation(operationN)
}
```

Comment: I don't want to block the user actually. It should happen in background only

Comment: @Saranjith, not clear how this relates to *blocking user*, provided block of code does not show any user-interaction use-case. Would you provide real minimal testable code?

Comment: it just synchronises your BlockOperation(s) within created OperationQueue.